# Cookies doesnot sets up

Tags: laravel, cookies, nuxt.js, csrf

I use Axios to get cookies from `http://localhost/sanctum/csrf-cookie`

My app doing requests from `localhost:3000` which is configured by Nuxt.
My backend configured by Laravel sanctum at `localhost:80`

After the GET request, I have the following cookies set in my headers:
[image]

> Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InkvSWhzeUtnYzNpck5NSGozS09IVVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRmR1RVdmYW8zaXYxeWZUNFNjZmkyNjRVKzZQMGk4MExsK3JmOVRPN0s3M3FGK3V1eFpLaTNRYnhhbExvTW5BbmFqVGN2SWRBdUVZcUJkWEJabnJQakEwN1pYNUk1NDBtRFhRSllkTk45ZHZuRWFUZmc5NHViK21JUTVkWFZhZDEiLCJtYWMiOiI5NjBkMWY5YWFmZTgwODE4ZjIzMzdjMjkxMzk3Zjk3YWU0YmI1ZGUzNzAyMmQzZWVhMWQzM2NmYWEwYjdhYTcxIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Sat, 01-Oct-2022 16:14:59 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=localhost:3000; samesite=lax

> Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InhNRVBDT1ovanR4QVdzakNHd1YxekE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiajNGUGdxa1NJemxiSGIrc1pwZ3VrNFJBbmd6QnFMZkZmZHdWK3ZPSzVWdGZydHBQTGNPRmpocVN3d1lTcTE1d0RLdWFNNEJPbjhLKzVPaEpvSTZzUm5RQWZaQ0ZHVlAxeElBVkErN2hOUnFRTm8wVGJrUllaNXNmTm50N1plTFoiLCJtYWMiOiIxNGZmNTYzYmFkMmY2NjAzNGQwMTIwMzhlYWNjYTI4MjQzNTM0N2Y4Mzk3MzkwYTdmYzU4MDFiMGVkZGU3NjVjIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Sat, 01-Oct-2022 16:14:59 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=localhost:3000; httponly; samesite=lax]

But there are no cookies in the application tab:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. In your .env file add

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
```

2. Check CORS

```php
    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'], // All origins

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

For your nuxt project, use [@nuxtjs/auth-next](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module) package.

Comment: Thanks for @nuxtjs/auth-next package. i read and rewrite the wrong credentials property in my axios setups

Comment: Great. If you need next/auth-next config, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem was wrong credentials support in axios module.

This should be the  credentials: true, rather than withCredentials: true

```
 axios: {
    credentials: true,
    baseURL: "http://localhost", // Used as fallback if no runtime config is provided
    // withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      common: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
      },
      delete: {},
      get: {},
      head: {},
      post: {},
      put: {},
      patch: {},
    },
  },
```